# print value of a column in django

Tags: python, django

How to print the test field in the following query in django

```
res=Resources.objects.filter(test=request.profile)
logging.debug(test) # won't work
```

I wanted to check what this value is compared with..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate through `res` and print each model's value of `test` in turn.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try the `values_list` method, eg:

```
Resource.objects.filter(test=request.profile).values_list("test")
```

It returns a list of tuples with the value of "test" for each matched record.